# Non-dispersive mediums for light

Tags: visible-light, refraction, dispersion, optical-materials

Apart from the vacuum are there other mediums for which light velocity does not depend on frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisely over a wide range of wavelengths, no. However, you can control the [dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(optics)) and in [waveguides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveguide), [photonic crystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photonic_crystal)  and [optical fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber) you can engineer the dispersion to be flat, or in other cases compensate dispersion by having the dispersion to be the opposite sign. This can be used to expand and compress [optical pulses](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Optical+pulses), or control light in other ways.